# How to get parent window in extjs or window.opener equivalent in extjs?

Tags: javascript, silverlight, extjs, silverlight-5.0, extjs4.1

I am launching a window using `HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(Uri, "_blank");` from silver light. I want to notify silverlight app from extjs unload event.

I am trying with window.opener from my extjs code in **app.js**

```
Ext.EventManager.on(window, 'beforeunload', function () {
            //window.opener is undefined here
            }
```

Is there any extjs equivalent for window.opener? Or How to get the parent window from extjs?
I am trying with the sample http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/293515/Calling-Silverlight-Method-from-Javascript-and-Jav for calling silverlight method from javascript?

Comment: your questions is very confused...extjs event or browser event? unload event or beforeunload event? why do you need the opener reference?

Comment: I don't think this is an ExtJS issue but rather browser support.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is an ExtJS issue but rather browser support.

Take a look at this question:
[window.opener alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4885765/window-opener-alternatives)