# Unable to get property of undefined or null reference

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

This is similar to my last question but the problem is different.  I use a separate javascript file for all of my javascript functions.  That file is called by my main window, and is also called in a separate instance by my child windows.  My code works with every browser except IE 9 and 10.  I have not tested earlier versions of IE.

IE says the offending line is `window.opener.savetoparent($targetval);`  My previous code was `opener.savetoparent($targetval);` and before that I simply made the changes to the parent from the child directly.  I have also gone into IE and enabled protected mode as suggested in another article with no change in behavior.  `Savetoparent()` is available to both the child and the parent so I must call it with opener for it to run in the parent.

The error I am getting is : `Unable to get property 'savetoparent' of undefined or null reference.`  Here is the code:

```
function saveandclose($wintype, $propid) {

switch($wintype) {
    case 'ccdetail':
        var $targetval = $('#cc-total').val();
        var $fieldname = 'closingcoststotal';
        break;
}

window.opener.savetoparent($targetval);
closewindow();
}
```

The safe to parent function is:

```
function savetoparent($targetval) {
    $('#' + $parentloc).val($targetval);
    var $name = $('#' + $parentloc).attr("name");
    var $rawtargetval = jsstrtonum($targetval);
    processrvsave($propertyid, $name, $rawtargetval);   
    calcrvtotals();
}
```

Any light you can shed on this would be greatly appreciated.

window is launched like this

```
if(window.showModalDialog) { 
  window.showModalDialog($childname + '.php?ploc=' + $parentloc + '&propid=' + $propid, '', 'dialogWidth: ' + $winwidth + 'px; dialogHeight: ' + $winheight + 'px;') 
} 
else { 
  window.open($childname + '.php?ploc=' + $parentloc + '&propid=' + $propid, '', 'width=' + $winwidth + ', height=' + $winheight + ', modal=yes'); 
}
```

Comment: did you open the child window using a script in the parent page?

Comment: Yes I did.  It is opened as a modal window

Comment: The code to launch is  

    if(window.showModalDialog) {
  window.showModalDialog($childname + '.php?ploc=' + $parentloc + '&propid=' + $propid, '', 'dialogWidth: ' + $winwidth + 'px; dialogHeight: ' + $winheight + 'px;')
 } else {
  window.open($childname + '.php?ploc=' + $parentloc + '&propid=' + $propid, '', 'width=' + $winwidth + ', height=' + $winheight + ', modal=yes');
 }

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4885765/window-opener-alternatives it appears the showModalDialog is your problem

Comment: Sorry for everything being inline.  I tried to edit but I ran out of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no opener in showModalDialog. Use the returnValue

Also there has not been a modal parameter on window.open in many years..

Here is how to use returnValue

```
if(window.showModalDialog) { 
  $targetval = window.showModalDialog($childname + '.php?ploc=' + $parentloc + '&propid=' + $propid, 
    window,
    'dialogWidth: ' + $winwidth + 'px; dialogHeight: ' + $winheight + 'px;'))
  if(targetval) savetoparent($targetval);
} 
else { 
  window.open($childname + '.php?ploc=' + $parentloc + '&propid=' + $propid, '', 'width=' + $winwidth + ', height=' + $winheight + ', modal=yes'); 
}
```

then

```
function saveandclose($wintype, $propid) {
  var $targetval ="";
  switch($wintype) {
    case 'ccdetail':
      $targetval = $('#cc-total').val();
      // var $fieldname = 'closingcoststotal'; I do not see this used anywhere
      break;
  }

  if (window.opener) window.opener.savetoparent($targetval);
  else returnValue = $targetval;
  closewindow();
}
```