# How to redirect to another page after closing the popup window in php which works fine for chrome and FF users

Tags: php, javascript, google-chrome

I have made a site where user login with google,where a popup window opens for login,when user click the submit button,the popup window close & user redirect to another page.

I have done the code but it works fine in FF bt not working in chrome

This is my code,can anyone plz suggest what changes I need to do so that it works in chrome also.

```
 <?php
   @session_start();
   require 'openid.php';
   try {


$openid = new LightOpenID;
if(!$openid->mode) {

    if(isset($_GET['login'])) {

        $openid->identity = 'https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id';
        $openid->required = array('namePerson/first', 'namePerson/last', 'contact/email');
       // @header('Location: ' . $openid->authUrl());
    echo "<script>location.href='".$openid->authUrl()."'</script>";
    }

} elseif($openid->mode == 'cancel') {
    echo 'User has canceled authentication!';
} else {
    if($openid->validate())
    {           
         'User <b>' . $openid->identity . '</b> has logged in.<br>';

         "<h3>User information</h3>";
        $_SESSION['identity'] = $openid->identity;
        $identity = $openid->identity;
        $attributes = $openid->getAttributes();
        $_SESSION['email'] = $attributes['contact/email'];
        $_SESSION['first_name'] = $attributes['namePerson/first'];
        $_SESSION['last_name'] = $attributes['namePerson/last'];


        /* "mode: " . $openid->mode . "<br>";
         "identity: " . $identity . "<br>";
         "email: " . $email . "<br>";
        "first_name: " . $first_name . "<br>";
         "last_name: " . $last_name . "<br>";*/


    }
    else
    {
        echo 'User ' . $openid->identity . 'has not logged in.';
    }


    echo "<script>window.close();</script>";
    echo '<script>window.opener.location.href="index2.php"</script>';



 }
    } catch(ErrorException $e) {
     echo $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

Comment: What does "not working" mean?

Answer (score 1):

i believe window.close() is not working in chrome for you.
Once i faced the problem i fixed the problem using

replace window.close(); with the code below

```
window.open('', '_self', ''); //simple bug fix
window.close();
```

Also try putting the this

```
echo '<script>window.opener.location.href="index2.php"</script>';
echo "<script>window.open('', '_self', '');window.close();</script>";
```

Hope it works for you too.

if not please be more specific about the question

Comment: You don't need two echo lines/script blocks for that.

Comment: I have used this which works fine in FF and chrome but not working in IE that means not redirecting to index2.php .Is there any way to do in IE also.

Comment: opener dont work in IE , try the alternatives here [Window Opener Alternatives](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4885765/window-opener-alternatives)

Answer (score 0):

Please try with below any one of the option

echo('opener.window.location.reload(true); window.close();');
or
 echo('window.opener.location.reload(false); window.close();');

if still problem exist let me know