# IE11 window.opener null after visit another site

Tags: null, cross-domain, internet-explorer-11, window.open

I'm using node.js + angularJS 1.5.7

when I use popup when External Authification or Purchase

ex> mysite => popup open(A) => Auth (like google) => post(A) => window.opener.postMessage

Script like this.

```
        /* request code */
        var child = null;
        child = window.open('', pop_title, opt);
        child.location = url;
        child.focus();
        var frmData = document.payForm;
        frmData.target = pop_title;
        frmData.action = url;
        frmData.submit();

        var leftDomain = false;
        var interval = setInterval(function () {
            try {
                if (child.document.domain === document.domain) {
                    if (leftDomain && child.document.readyState === "complete") {
                        clearInterval(interval);
                        child.postMessage({message: "requestResult"}, "*");
                    }
                } else {
                    leftDomain = true;
                }
            } catch (e) {
                // we're here when the child window has been navigated away or closed
                if (child.closed) {
                    clearInterval(interval);
                    return;
                }
                // navigated to another domain
                leftDomain = true;
            }
        }, 500);

        /* child page */
        document.domain = "mysite.com"
        targetWindow = window.opener;
        targetWindow.postMessage({ message: "deliverResult", result: "succ" , msg: "¿¿¿ ¿¿ ¿¿¿ ¿¿¿¿¿¿¿.", tid: "<?=$_POST["Tradeid"]?>"}, "*");
```

this code works in Edge or Chrome. 
But IE11 doesn't work.

I tried Another way

```
        localStorage.setItem("orgWindow",window);
        localStorage.getItem("orgWindow");
```

But this not working too. Window is Found. But Opener is null.

I use IFrame when IE11 temporary. But I want Popup All browser.

Please give me any idea please.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you check the documentation for Window.Opener than you will notice that compatibility for IE is unknown.

Reference: 
[Window.opener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/opener)

It can be the possible reason that why it is not working as expected in IE. You can try to use alternative approach like in the link below.

[window.opener alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4885765/window-opener-alternatives)